# BMP color replacer: Algorithm for padding doesn't work

Tags: c, bitmap, padding, bmp

I am building a function that replaces a color in a BMP image with another target color.
It works as long as I don't attempt to replace a color in image that requires padding.
However, I am almost certain that the way I account padding is correct.. So for me this is a complete mystery.

---

[image]

---

*330 x 250 (248 054 bytes) Hi-color 24bit bitmap*

---

This is the function:

```
union
{
    unsigned long ulColor;
    unsigned char byteColor[4];
} oldColor;
union
{
    unsigned long ulColor;
    unsigned char byteColor[4];
} newColor;

typedef unsigned char           BYTE;
typedef unsigned short int      WORD;
typedef unsigned long int       DWORD;
typedef unsigned long long int  DDWORD;

DDWORD
bitfox_color_replace_data
(BYTE *buff, BYTE old_r, BYTE old_g, BYTE old_b, BYTE new_r, BYTE new_g, BYTE new_b)
{
    #define OFFSET_OF_SIZE      0x2
    #define OFFSET_OF_PIXELS    0xA
    #define OFFSET_OF_WIDTH     0x12
    #define OFFSET_OF_HEIGHT    0x16

    DWORD* buffSize     = (DWORD*)&buff[OFFSET_OF_SIZE];
    DWORD* buffPixels   = (DWORD*)&buff[OFFSET_OF_PIXELS];
    DWORD* buffWidth    = (DWORD*)&buff[OFFSET_OF_WIDTH];
    DWORD  buffHeight   = 0;

    BYTE pad            = 0;
    
    DDWORD pixels_replaced = 0;
    DDWORD i;

    oldColor.byteColor[0] = old_b;  newColor.byteColor[0] = new_b;
    oldColor.byteColor[1] = old_g;  newColor.byteColor[1] = new_g;
    oldColor.byteColor[2] = old_r;  newColor.byteColor[2] = new_r;
    
    for(i = (*buffPixels); i < (*buffSize); i += 3)
    {
        if( i == ((*buffPixels) + (((*buffWidth) * 3) + pad) * (buffHeight + 1)) )
        {
            pad = ((*buffWidth) % 4);
            buffHeight++;
            i += pad;
        }
        
        if(!memcmp(buff + i, oldColor.byteColor, 3))
        {
            memcpy(buff + i, newColor.byteColor, 3);

            pixels_replaced++;
        }

    }
    return pixels_replaced;
}
```

What am I possibly doing wrong ?

Comment: If you provided a way to read in the file, so the code could be stepped through, it might be easier to spot an error.  The question I have looking at it statically centers around the _condition statement_ used to enter the `pad =` statement.  I do not understand the criteria for choosing the conditions you chose: `if( i == ((*buffPixels) + (((*buffWidth) * 3) + pad) * (buffHeight + 1)) )`

Comment: @ryyker Try to figure out a way to consider padding in this particular function and you might end up with something like that too. `i` also reaches the padding so it needs to be included in the formula that determines whether `i` is at the end of a line of pixels.

Comment: Can you rewrite that pointer mess to a routine using an `y` counter for the height and an `x` counter for the width? I suspect if you do so *and* still take padding into account, the problem mysteriously disappears.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with bitmaps, there are three parameters that you need to know: height, width, and stride. Width and height are obvious. The `stride` is the number of bytes per line including padding.

Here's one way to compute the `stride`. Note that the `stride` must be a multiple of 4.

```
int stride = ((width * 3) + 3) >> 2;
stride *= 4;
```

The first line computes the minimum number of 4-byte values that can hold a line. The second line converts the `stride` to a byte count.

The code at the end of this post demonstrates how to use the stride. The code assumes that the input file contains a 24bpp RGB image. The file headers have already been read, leaving just the pixel data, which is read into a `buffer`. The code writes to an output file, assuming the output image is the same size as the input image and any headers have already been written.

The important lines are

```
size = height * stride;           // total number of bytes in the image, including padding

offset = (y * stride) + (x * 3);  // 'y * stride' is the offset to the beginning of a line
                                  // 'x * 3' computes the byte offset of a particular pixel

for ( x=width*3; x<stride; x++ )  // outputs the padding bytes, if needed,
    fputc( 0, fpout );
```

---

```
unsigned char *buffer = NULL;

int height = bmpinfo.biHeight;
int width  = bmpinfo.biWidth;

// stride = (width * 3), rounded up to a multiple of 4
int stride = ((width * 3) + 3) >> 2;    
stride *= 4;

// size of the pixel data, including padding
size_t size = height * stride;         

// allocate memory for the pixel data
if ( (buffer = malloc( size )) == NULL )
    error( "Insufficient memory" );

// read the pixel data from the file
if ( fread( buffer, 1, size, fpin ) != size )
    error( "Unable to read image data" );

// process pixels by row and column
for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
{
    for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
    {
        // get the RGB values from the buffer
        offset = (y * stride) + (x * 3);
        blue  = buffer[offset];
        green = buffer[offset+1];
        red   = buffer[offset+2];

        // mess around with the RGB value here

        // write the new RGB values to the file
        fputc( (int)blue , fpout );
        fputc( (int)green, fpout );
        fputc( (int)red  , fpout );
    }

    // write the padding bytes to the file
    for ( x = width*3; x < stride; x++ )
        fputc( 0, fpout );
}
```

Comment: Well umm.. I don't know what to say. What does that has to do with my question? What does that has to do with direct color replace of a memory-buffered bmp? Also my function is clearly meant to be fast.

Comment: @AlanSalios I was just answering the question in the title, "BMP color replacer: Algorithm for padding". I was showing you how to correctly account for padding in a bitmap image. Note that fast is meaningless if it doesn't work, and [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Comment: I know how to account padding. I have built functions that create, read, negate bmp files and they all work doubtless and fast. But the complications I ran into are in that function. My algorithm for determininng padding should work. Also the question is not in the title. It is in the question's body. I am wondering why my algorithm doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Ok, well I wasn't going to say anything, but when I read your code, I couldn't make heads or tails of it. (Based on the comments, I wasn't the only one.) I suggest then that you edit the question in an attempt to explain to people how your code is supposed to work. Then perhaps, someone can spot the flaw.

Comment: I think it is obvious. I also gave an exemplification. It simply works, it replaces old colors to new colors. When I try to replace colors in a padded image, the image gets distorted as the picture exemplifies.. I don't know what more to say.. there is one line of algorithm for considering padding and it doesn't work.. what more..

Comment: *"It simply works ... and it doesn't work"* Good luck, I hope that you are able to solve the problem. Sorry I tried to help by showing you code that actually works ... and actually works.

Comment: ..I said it works as long as I don't --- . And your code doesn't work, because it has nothing to do with my function i.e it doesn't replace colors. fast.

Comment: @AlanSalios your code only works ... when `pad == 0` because it is incorrect. You work out `pad` *once* per image, not once per line. Your code starts with `pad = 0` and then recalculates it *after* you have used it. This answer shows the difference between `width` and `stride` and discards the use of `pad` because it is not necessary.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay that was my question. Why is it incorrect. I didn't even asked for fix. Just why the code fails. I don't understand how come it calculates it once per image. That makes no sense. Also it is meant to calculate it the next time.

Comment: It's incorrect because your solution is trying to parse the image in a single loop. It should be using two nested loops as this answer is showing, and @Jongware commented. The solution is to do that, and not struggle to fix a poor method.